# UITableViewController change navigation button

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button

I have several UITableViewControllers where I am trying to change the background image of the "back" button or navigation button (see image below). How is this possible?

[button http://casperslynge.dk/button](http://casperslynge.dk/button)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `tintColor` of the `UINavigationBar`.

For more information, please refer to this link: [tintColor in UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW9)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

we can use tintcolor but in that only some default will be there we can use use those colors only

```
toolbar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```